# TableView Images displays only when scrolled down

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am loading a tableview with images. These are loaded asynchronously. 
The images only get displayed with i scroll the tableview.

I know this happens because of the reusable cells inside the tableview. My code is as follows.

How can i prevent this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCell *c = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (c == nil)

    {

        c = [[MyCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

                                      reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    }



    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ss.com/my.png"];

    NSURLRequest *r = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [c.myImageView setImageWithURLRequest:r placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"def.png"] success:^(NSURLRequest *request,   NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

        if (c)

        {

            c. myImageView.image = image;

            [c setNeedsLayout];

        }

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

Comment: r u using **AFNETWORKING** or else for show the image (setImageWithURLRequest)

Comment: Yes, i am using AFNetworking. What is the workaround with `SDWebimage`

Answer (score 1):

In this case use lazy loading technique. As if we have to show the images in table view lazy loading is best technique. here is the library
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage
Just add the SDWebImage folder in your project. 
Then in your class import the following

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

and in cellforRowIndex method write the following code

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ss.com/my.png"];
[c.myImageView setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"def.png"]];
```

No need for success failure block as it will lazy load images and will keep them in cache by making as a key itself. So if the image is already loaded once then next time when you will open this controller, it will show up as if was in your local storage. Thats the benefit of this library

Comment: It still doesn't download or display the default image. Only when i scroll it appears.

Comment: wait for some time. and it will appear

Comment: next time when you load this view again..it will not make a call and the image will be present..as it is stored in cache

Comment: I have a problem. Previously before importing `SDWebView` library i had imported `#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
`. So when i type the code provided by you it came from the  `AFNetworking` library. Thereafter, i removed the `AFNetworking` library. Now, `setImageWithURL ` doesn't show up. Help.

Comment: clean the project.. or you might change the method in library also....no need to remove anything..just make another method with different name..inside the library